# Regular Expression to read csv file on post processor

Tags: jmeter

i have one requirement, it might be simple but not getting any clue. Actually in my jmeter script i am getting one http response as csv file. The same file i need to read into my post processor script which is groovy script. Any one has any idea how to do this, struggling from past couple of days but not getting any clue.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly got your use case, you have:

1. HTTP Sampler which is hitting some CSV file
2. Some Post Processor in which you want to read data from this CSV file

If you look into View Results Tree listener into your request, which retrieves CSV file you should see this CSV file contents.

JMeter provides powerful [BeanShell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) which is capable of interacting with JMeter Context. It's as simple as next line:

```
vars.put("myCSV",prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

Another option is to store response data as a new CSV file as follows:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("my.csv");
out.write(prev.getResponseData());
out.flush();
out.close();
```

As the result of above you'll store your response as file "my.csv" in the folder, from where you launched JMeter (usually /bin folder of your JMeter installation).

After that you will be able to use "my.csv" file in [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) to iterate through the variables as usual.